# How to successfully move an SSD encrypted with Debian 11 to another computer with different hardware

Tags: linux, command-line, boot, ssd, debian

I installed Debian 11 Bullseye on an SSD drive and want to physically move the drive to another computer with different hardware.
On boot on the new machine it gives this error: `Failed to start Load Kernel Modules`, it also gives errors due to not finding Nvidia GPU, old computer had Nvidia GPU.
The system boots normally in CLI mode on the new machine, except freezing after 15/20 minutes, but on GUI it freezes right after I login to the user.
I tried booting the system in recovery mode, booting the system as root, changing DEs, updated packages through CLI. Nothing worked.
I would love to just boot into my system's GUI again. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think it is evident that the actual software installed in the installation process depends on what kind of hardware you have inte machine you do it on. If you then move the disk to another machine with a load of differences, why do you expect it to be "easy" to get it running? Much of the software has a hard time to find corresponding hardware, is that surprising? **The easy way out of this:** Reinstall, on the machine you intend to use the disk in.